# Javafx add text to a progress bar inside a table

Tags: javafx, progress

I've been working with javafx tables and managed to add a Table Column with progress bars using `progressBarColumn.setCellFactory(ProgressBarTableCell.forTableColumn());`, it  uses a dummy Person class to get its data not `javafx.concurrent.Task`.

All works well but i was wondering if you could also add text to the progress bars in the table, sort of like swings `JProgressBar` `setString(String string)`.

I'm rather noobish with javafx so i don't know much about it.

Comment: you could also draw the pane that will have the progress bar and the label in the place you want and use this as the column for the table so you would have access to both the label and the progress bar at any time for any column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it using `ProgressBarTableCell`. You need to use a **custom** Control for it.

You can use the custom control, [`ProgressIndicatorBar`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14061347/1759128), created by JewelSea and add it to your `progressBarColumn`.

For more information on how to add Controls to TableColumn, you can check this answer

[JavaFX: Add UI control to TreeTableView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26237863/1759128)

*It adds it to a `TreeTableView`, but you can apply the same logic for `TableView` as well.*